# PrincipalThreadLocal.getUserId() is 0 for Icefaces (1.8.2) portlets

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2, icefaces-1.8

I am basically implementing logger on the generic actions like saving portlet's preferences in `store` method of `PortletPreferencesImpl`. Here I am calling `PrincipalThreadLocal.getUserId()` to get user information.

Everything is fine for the **Liferay OTB's** portlets and for **Primefaces 5.2** portlets but when I am saving preferences of **Icefaces (1.8.2)** portlet, I am always getting `0` from `PrincipalThreadLocal.getUserId()`.

Why is this strange behavior?
Please share your valuable feedback.

Comment: Cross posted: [***Liferay Forum***](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/87782723)

Comment: Have you checked, if IceFaces is using a thread different from the portlet thread (`new Exception().printStackTrace()` right before the call to `getUserId()` should show you the stacktrace of the current thread)?

Comment: I have already checked, there is nothing special in the stack-trace. After invoking my preferences class action, store of PortletPreferencesImpl is called.

Comment: The only difference that I have figured out is that the `service` method of `MainServlet` is being invoked for other portlet types except Icefaces. And to add more interest this servlet is setting the `userId` in `name` property of `PrincipalThreadLocal`.

Comment: One can find further information regarding this post on [***Liferay Forum***](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/87816062) thread.